# grub missing after laptop maintenance

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, debian

I cleaned my laptop fan today, having to remove my hard disk.
Now, grub is missing : my laptop boots on windows automatically.
I had a debian testing - windows dualboot.

Boot Mode : [UEFI]

Secure boot [Disabled]

Network Boot; F12 Boot Menu; D2D Recovery; Wake on LAN are all [Disabled]

Sata Mode : [AHCI Mode]

And windows fastboot is desactivated.

I have tried Boot-repair on an ubuntu live session but it doesn't work, it prints : 'grub-efi purge cancelled. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com'

Here is my boot info : http://paste.ubuntu.com/11742170/

What can i do? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Which boot option is selected in UEFI?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Debian is *unfortunately* off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: I understand this topic is about ubuntu but since it concerns grub i assumed it worked the same way for debian or ubuntu. So someone using ubuntu may experience the same issue, isn't it right ?

Comment: the pre-existent debian tag should be destroyed then ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the tip at the end of the boot info :

I used `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi`

but i have to do it every time i restart my computer -_-'